# Wifi card error

Tags: hardware-failure

When I opened my laptop Lenovo G450 I got a message "Unauthorized network card is plugged in. Power off and remove the miniPCI netword card". I cannot access BIOS by pressing F2 on boot to check the settings. I cannot do anything except turning off the laptop by pressing the power button. Things done sor far:

1. Remove LAN card.
2. Replaced with known good RAM.
3. Hard reset by removing the battery ang press power button for 60 seconds.

According to my research that Lenovo have whitelisted  for the device to comply with various countries legislation regarding radio interference. I am just wondering why LAN card is rejected now considering that I am using same card and it was working before. It seems my card are not included on the whitelist of lenovo.

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing this has nothing to do with a whitelist or blacklist, and everything to do with faulty hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers block "unauthorized" wifi cards from being installed in the laptop. Lenovo is obviously one. HP is another common manufacturer to block wifi cards.

The message is indicating that the wifi adapter you have installed is not authorized to be used on the system, and there will be no way past it but to remove the wifi adapter and install a properly approved adapter. True, there are some BIOS hacks out there, but there is a high risk of bricking your computer.

It's not clear from your question if you ever changed the wifi card. But, you seem to indicate "it was working before" and that it is not "included on the whitelist of Lenovo." So, I'm assuming you have changed it. I can't tell you why it worked before, but possibly you changed your BIOS version.

Therefore, you can remove the wifi adapter for now so that the computer will boot properly. Next, purchase and install an approved wifi adapter for the laptop to restore proper functionality.

Comment: I did not changed my wifi card. I am still using the same wifi card when i bought sometime 2011. If it was working before that means my card is included on the whitelist of lenovo. Also i did not change the bios version because i dont know how to do it. It was working flawlessly the night before i got the message. I already remove the wifi card but when i turn same message will appear

Comment: This is why I assume this has nothing to do with a whitelist of blacklist, and everything to do with faulty hardware. The question is whether the WiFi card is the faulty hardware, or the laptop is, or both.